# Is there a list of textmark tags in word

Tags: microsoft-word, shortcuts

I know you can set textmarks in word using the shortcut CTRL + F9 and refeer to specific parts of your text like the current page or the number of pages of your whole document
Those Tags look like {PAGE} or {NUMPAGE}.
I'm really interessted in a list of more tags and especially for a tag which refeers to the current chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most complete list you are likely to find is [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/list-of-all-possible-field-codes-for-microsoft/28439816-2daa-4cdd-a7cd-4fe5017bf084) . You can find more details of most of the fields that people actually use

- in Microsoft's documentation, although it isn't always easy to
  navigate (e.g. you can find the STYLEREF field documentation
  [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/field-codes-styleref-field-HP005186193.aspx), or
- in the ECMA/ISO standards documentation and Microsoft's related
  implementation notes.

The issue of chapter headings and numbering in Word is a tricky one.

Mostly, Microsoft Word expects you to do "chapters" by using the built-in Heading styles, and picking one style (could be Heading 1, Heading 2 etc. to be the "Chapter" level - i.e., each new Heading 1 paragraph introduces a new chapter. Using Heading styles is important if you want to use certain facilities such as chapter-page numbering (you can only pick Heading styles for the chapter numbering).

But there isn't a simple { CHAPTER } field to go with that. The nearest thing for most purposes is probably the { STYLEREF } field. For example, if you opt for using Heading 2 style as your Chapter style, you can use { STYLEREF "Heading 2" } to insert the Chapter heading, or you can avoid internationalisation problems by using the undocumented { STYLEREF 2 }. However, if you want to insert a chapter number, you are then dependent on using Word's automatic numbering for that style (typically in a multilevel list numbering scheme). If you do that, you can extract the number as shown in the heading using e.g. { STYLEREF 2 \n }.

If you set up your numbering to use "Chapter N. Chapter title", e.g. "Chapter 1. Introduction", then you can strip out the "Chapter" part using { STYLEREF 2 \n \t }. If you actually need a sequence number, you can probably extract what you need if your numbering scheme uses the numerical sequence 1,2,3... or 1., 2., 3., or Chapter 1, Chapter 2, Chapter 3, but not if you use something like Chapter A, Chapter B. If you do that, then your best bet is probably to put a field like { SEQ Chap \h } in each chapter heading, and use { SEQ Chap \c } to reference it.

Another thing to bear in mind is that { STYELREF } in the document body will typically reference the previous paragraph of the specified style. { STYLEREF } in a header will typically reference the first paragraph of the given style on the page if there is one, or the last one on a preceding page if there isn't.

In theory, there are also other ways to do chapter numbering - for example, you can implement your own scheme using { SEQ } fields. IN that case, you might use { SEQ Chapter } to number each chapter. Then you can always use { SEQ Chapter \c } to insert the current chapter number. But mostly, these should be avoided because users don't understand them, there is no automatic updating of SEQ fields, and they don't generally play well with Word's cross-referencing, index and tables of contents features.